# Displaying after one week Date in second field automatically with respect to the date entered in first field

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, datepicker, nsdate

I have two text fields where if i enter a date in the first text field...i should get the date exactly one week with reference to that date in the second field.I searched in NSDate but not able to get it.

Any suggestions please

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May following code will help you :

```
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
   int daysToAdd = 50;  // or 60 :-)

    // set up date components
    NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [components setDay:daysToAdd];

    // create a calendar
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

    NSDate *newDate2 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];
    NSLog(@"Clean: %@", newDate2);

    //for displaying date in text field
    txt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newDate2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,let me implement and get back to you :)

Comment: Yeah Mr.Stark,the logic worked perfect,it is getting displayed in console,but not in required field,please suggest what should I do...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: hey Eshwar Chaitanya i have edited my answer as per your comment...please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *newDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(86400 * 4)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer,will implement it and get back to you :)

Comment: No. Do not use hard-coded times like this. This will break under certain conditions.